# Replacing two MINUS/EXCEPT queries

Tags: sql, oracle

When confirming that turning to stored procedures does not brake their intended functionality (data from point A gets to point B), I often use `MINUS` (`EXCEPT` in sql server).  However this forces me to run each query twice (since minus returns the rows that exist in the first/top table that do not exist in the second/bottom):

```
SELECT value1, value2, value3 FROM table1 WHERE uploadID = 'beforeTurning'
MINUS
SELECT value1, value2, value3 FROM table1 WHERE uploadID = 'afterTurning';

SELECT value1, value2, value3 FROM table1 WHERE uploadID = 'afterTurning'
MINUS
SELECT value1, value2, value3 FROM table1 WHERE uploadID = 'beforeTruning';
```

**Could I accomplish the same thing with one query? How would I do it?**

Comment: Your query wouldn't even exclude anything, because values in the first query and second will allways differ at least by the field uploadID ('beforeTunning' in the first part and 'afterTunning' in the second). So, nothing will be excluded from the first query.

Comment: @Mikhail I will update my example :)

Comment: Well then just use NOT EXISTS :) Something like that  `SELECT value1, value2, value3 FROM table1 t1 WHERE uploadID = 'beforeTunning' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 t2 WHERE t1.value1 = t2.value1 AND t1.value2 = t2.value2 AND t1.value3 = t2.value3 AND t2.uploadID = 'afterTunning') UNION SELECT value1, value2, value3 FROM table1 t1 WHERE uploadID = 'afterTunning' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 t2 WHERE t1.value1 = t2.value1 AND t1.value2 = t2.value2 AND t1.value3 = t2.value3 AND t2.uploadID = 'beforeTunning')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  value1, value2, value3,
  sum(decode(uploadID, 'afterTurning', 1, 'beforeTurning', -1)) AS diff
FROM table1 
GROUP BY value1, value2, value3
HAVING sum(decode(uploadID, 'afterTurning', 1, 'beforeTurning', -1)) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
WITH
  BeforeAfter AS (
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE uploadID = 'beforeTunning'
    MINUS SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE uploadID = 'afterTunning'),
  AfterBefore AS (
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE uploadID = 'afterTunning'
    MINUS SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE uploadID = 'beforeTunning')
SELECT * FROM BeforeAfter
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM AfterBefore
```

A `UNION` might work better for you than a `UNION ALL` - your call there.